# Is there any way to use an audio player without Flash?

Tags: audio-streaming, audio-player

I would like to add an audio player in my HTML page. Is there any way to play the audio file with a simple player without using Flash player?

Comment: You can include a flash player in your  application. Try  flajector. It must help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag. There is already a nice solution called [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/)

Comment: HTML5 is not supported in all older browsers.

Comment: That's true. Other solutions I can think of (java applet, silverlight) unfortunately require proprietary plugins and need installation so I think this is your best bet.